# Set "Selected Item" in multiselect RadComboBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radcombobox

Is there any way we can set Selected Items or Checked Items in a multiselect RadComboBox ?. I want to set value on postback from server.

I tried following code but that works only if it is not a multiselect RadComboBox.

`Radbox1.SelectedValue = "123"`

My front end code.

`<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Radbox1" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"
    Width="300" Height="200" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Radbox1_SelectedIndexChanged" />`

I have value in Radbox1 which will be populated from database.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the Radcombobox is set to allow multiple selections via the checkboxes, you must use each items checked property.

I use a list here to simulate the items that I wish to have marked on postback. You could have this list pre-populated or it could even be loaded from a database:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void RadComboBox1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadComboBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ("YourString" == e.Item.Text))
    {
        e.Item.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Or

```
protected void RadComboBox1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadComboBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
    List<String> yourStringList = new List<String>() {"string1","string2"};
    if (yourStringList.Contains(e.Item.Text))
    {
         e.Item.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done something like this; **Machine_Serial_Numbers** is a **telerik:RadComboBox**;

```
foreach (var machine in bulletinData.Machines)
        {
            var comboItem = Machine_Serial_Numbers.FindItemByValue(machine.Id.ToString());

            if (comboItem != null)
            {
                comboItem.Checked = true;
            }                
        }
```

This worked for me.

[image]